# Best way to process daily data on Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, etl

I have a lending platform and need to process the current balance of all active contracts daily (adding interest, default interest, discounts, etc...).

Today I'm loading all rows, and for each one I check the current status, but it is becoming reeeeally slow to do that.

I'm a backend developer, but does not have much experience in data engineering stuff, but I know it must be a better way, but don't know how to search about it.

**Update**
A naive example of what the code is doing:

```
  for(loan in loans) {
    if (loan.isLate()) {
       loan.penaltyInterest += calculator.getPenaltyInterestFor(loan);
       loan.fine = calculator.getFineForloan);
    }

    loan.interest += calculator.getInterestFor(loan);
    loan.update();
  }
```

We have more than 100k active loans, and it is very expensive to run (the calculator do some processing intensive tasks).

Can anyone give me some advice on how to handle this case better, or what I need to look for?

Comment: Is your Postgres table partitioned in any way based on the day? If you wanted to use Hadoop/Spark (your previous tags), there's tutorials elsewhere on how you can install and use them

Comment: Your code is going record by record in your database or are you loading the data into postgres and then running and `UPDATE` query to change these values?

Comment: what's "best" depends on far more than the information you've given; but generally "batching" up multiple bits of work to amortise runtime costs can be good, also postgres can be cleverer if you give it more work to do, e.g. prefetching 100 rows needed by the calculations can be orders of magnitude faster than fetching them on demand

Comment: This would be a lot more answerable if you shared exactly the code that you are using today so we can understand if you are looping through a recordset in some non-sql language, or if you are applying this logic through an update statement. If it is an update statement, then also share the table DDL and any indexing that is present on the table.